# Grails Tomcat root context and double slash (//) in URLs

Tags: tomcat, grails

`My grails application is deployed under the ROOT context in Tomcat 7.0.32 running on Debian Stable. I enabled this by setting apache-tomcat-7.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Context path="" docBase="/home/tomcat/explodedWarDirectory/" antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />
```

When the Grails `g:link` tag is evalutaed or a `redirect()` from a controller is invoked, all URLs contain `//` at the beginning, presumably because the context is empty.

So, I changed the above configuration to `<Context path="/"` but still have the same problem.

How can I get the link or redirects working correctly so I don't have `//` at the beginning of my URLs?

Comment: You don't need a `path="....."` at all as the context path to use is inferred from the name of the file (`ROOT.xml` means the root context, `foo.xml` means `/foo`, etc.).  Try just `<Context docBase="..."`

Comment: I've removed that attribute but no luck! Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: You might also check that `grails.serverURL` in `Config.groovy` does not have a trailing slash...

Comment: Thanks Andrew - it was a trailing slash causing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this, thanks to Andrew in the comments.

In `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` I had a trailing slash for the server's URL (in our production section):

`grails.serverURL = "http://ourhostname/"`

Removing the trailing slash resolved it.